# Не работает программа на обычном СИ

Tags: c, матрицы

Нашла решение задачи на С. Условие такое:

Для заданной матрицы размером 4х4 найти такие k, что k-я строка матрицы совпадает с k-м столбцом. Найти сумму элементов в тех строках, которые содержат хотя бы один отрицательный элемент.
Проблема в том, что на размере 8х8 что-то ещё получается, а на 4х4 вообще ерунда.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

 int     matrix[8][8] = {
                           { 2, 7, 2, 7, 1, 4, 0, 3 },
                           { 1, 0, 7, 6, 0, -8, 3, 5 },
                           { 2, 7, 1, 8, 1, 4, 9, 3 },
                           { 9, 2, 8, 5, 2, 0, 0, 6 },
                           { 7, 1, 1, 3, 9, 3, 9, 1 },
                           { 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, -6, 4, 9 },
                           { 0, 3, 9, 0, 9, 4, 8, 8 },
                           { 1, 8, 3, 2, 8, 2, 8, 0 }
                           };
    int     i, j, iSumm; 
    bool    bFlag;

    printf("k = ");
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {

        bFlag = true;
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {

            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i])
            {
                bFlag = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (bFlag) printf("%d ", i);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {

        bFlag = false;
        iSumm = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {

            if (matrix[i][j] < 0) bFlag = true;

            iSumm += matrix[i][j];
        }

        if (bFlag) printf("Сумма элементов строки #%d = %d\n", i, iSumm);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Пожалуйста, если можно, то помогите ещё со второй задачей. Я тут сколько пыталась, ничего не получилось.  Вот условие:  проверить, все ли строки матрицы упорядочены по убыванию. Если нет, найти первую неупорядоченную строку и упорядочить.

Answer (score 1):

При поиске одинаковых строк и столбца необходим не вложенный цикл как у Вас, а ОДНОВРЕМЕННОЕ прохождение по очередным строке и столбцу.

Comment: @BuilderC, именно это тут и делается. Да и как еще Вы предлагаете обходить матрицу, у которой два измерения, если не двойным циклом?

--------

Основная проблема ТС в двух вещах:

1) Противоречие самому себе

> ... Нашла решение задачи на СИ ...
> ... Вот мой код ...

2) Даже если Вы девушка, то без наличия элементарных знаний и желания разобраться в задаче, снисхождения Вы тут не найдете и готовый код просто так никто не будет торопиться выкладывать. Тут все равны(ну ладно, почти равны ;)).

Comment: @Alex Krass, даже если Вы уже (еще) не девушка, то могли бы понять, что циклы (вложенные) должны быть иными, чем у вопрошающего. Внешний - по строкам, а внутренний - одновременно по строке и столбцу. Т.е. во внутреннем цикле индексы столбца и данной строки должны меняться ОДНОВРЕМЕННО.

Comment: @BuilderC, а Вы проанализируйте тщательно алгоритм или даже запустите на выполнение. )) Программа 100% рабочая и правильная (ну, за исключением отсутствия в Си типа bool и слов true, false). Я понимаю, что в Интернете описан код только для матрицы 8 на 8, но почему ТС не смог вместо восьмерки подставить четверку в нужных местах, если это ее код, мне непонятно.

Comment: @Alex Krass, алгоритм, конечно, будет работать. Но то, что  он пробегает почти все столбцы впустую для каждого элемента строки, Вас не беспокоит?

Comment: @BuilderC, либо я Вас совсем не понимаю, либо Вы пытаетесь сказать алгоритм, чтобы сравнить каждую строку с каждым столбцом. Обращаю внимание, что в задание сказано k-й с k-м, то есть для матрицы 4x4:

    (1 строка ?= 1 столбец )
    (2 строка ?= 2 столбец )
    (3 строка ?= 3 столбец )
    (4 строка ?= 4 столбец )

И больше проверок никаких не надо. Для одной строки нас интересует один конкретный столбец, что меня должно беспокоить? В общем, прошу тогда хотя бы псевдокод ваших мыслей.

Comment: @Alex Krass, Вы правы. Приношу извинения.